# Multiple Slack Account

Tags: windows, slack

Is it possible to run more than one slack account on the desktop app?

I mean, I am currently working for different clients but in one I am using an email account they provided and, with the rest, I am just using mine.

So, I would like to know if it possible to have It all under one desktop window or if I can have two (2) desktop windows running? One for each email?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign into another workspace, click the workspace name in the app, where it has the down arrow next to it. You should see an option that says `Sign in to another workspace`

That will open a new web browser with a page where you sign in with your email.

If that email is associated with more than one workspace, it will give you the option to choose which workspace you want to sign into. If you're wanting to do both, I think you will have to go through the `Sign in to another workspace` process again with the same email.

Once you are signed into the workspaces, you will be able to see them individually on the left hand side.